# Understanding the try-block

Tags: c++, exception, error-handling, try-catch, error-checking

I'm studying C++ by 2 months and I'm having some problem with understanding the try-catch block in C++. I'm using the book : programming principles and practice using C++, here is what my book says :

> > the basic idea of the exceptions is that if a function find is an error that it cannot handle, it does not return normally, instead, it **throw**s an exception indicating what went wrong. Any direct or indirect caller can **catch** the exception, that is, specify what to do if the called code used **throw**.

**What does "any direct or indirect caller can cacht the exception** means ? does the author means the caller of a function or the catch function ?". I'm confused about this, Could you exaplain it to me in simple way ?

Comment: Note that you have selected the only answer, but the quote in your question is about direct or indirect callers of *functions*. Indirect means the caller calls `foo()` which then calls `bar()`. `bar()` throws, `foo()` doesn't catch, but the caller can catch. The examples in the answer are missing one function call.

Comment: @juanchopanza can you please explain that to me with a more detailed comment ? I didn't understand you, sorry.

Comment: I don't know how to else to explain it. The answer has a direct function call (the one it calls "indirect") and no function call at all (the one it calls "direct".)

Comment: @juanchopanza Why error checking shoul be done in a function call (in the case of functions) and the error handling should be done in the calling function ?

Comment: It doesn't have to be. But that is what the quote is talking about. It is talking about function calls and where the error handling gets done by *callers* of those functions.

Answer (score 4):

Example for indirect call:
Here the exception happens in the called function. But the try catch is placed in the calling function, and not the called function.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

using namespace std;
void divideByZero(){
    int a = 5;

    int b = a / 0;
    throw(b);
}
int main()
{
    try{
        divideByZero();
    }
    catch (exception& e){
        cout<<e.what()<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Example for direct exception:
Here the exception happens in the functions itself directly, and handled there itself.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    try{
        int a = 5;
        int b = a / 0;
        throw(b);
    }
    catch (exception& e){
        cout<<e.what()<<endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The above program is used only for illustration and not for any real example, which you are likely to come across when you write a useful program.

Comment: Well, it might. It's undefined behavior. It would certainly be better to give an example with well defined behavior.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley correct, the proper way is to say that "the standard does not specify throwing an exception in this case"

Comment: Your "indirect" example is actually direct. Your "direct" example doesn't even have a function call. You need one more level of function calls.